# SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize returning 10000 for TableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I am placing a UITableHeaderView into the HeaderView of a parent UITableView. I am using AutoLayout for Height and Weight and am following the standard approach shown in many StackOverflow Answers of calling

```
view.SetNeedsLayout();
view.LayoutIfNeeded();
var height = view.SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UIView.UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).Height;

CGRect headerFrame = new CGRect(view.Frame.X, view.Frame.Y, view.Frame.Width, height);
view.Frame = headerFrame;

view.SetNeedsLayout();
view.LayoutIfNeeded();
```

This is an approach that works fine on the Footer but for the headerView SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize is returning 10000 for height. Which is clearly wrong.

Does anyone know why it would return what seems to be a maxheight constant of 10000?

Comment: Show your actual code... First guess, you are in a loop, where each time you set the header that triggers another call for the header, which triggers another call, etc etc etc, and each call you are increasing the height.

Comment: I am not in a loop at all. I have added the C# code I am using in my Xamarin iOS project

Comment: I didn't mean you were in a "coded" loop - what my suspicion was is that setting the Frame would trigger a new call to "get header" which would now set the Frame taller (because it just got the height set) which would trigger a new call to "get header" which would now set the Frame taller (because it just got the height set) which would trigger a new call to "get header" which would now set the Frame taller (because it just got the height set) which would trigger a new call to "get header" and so on... maybe show more code? When is this code running? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: It's called from ViewDidLayoutSubviews. I can debug that code to see if it called multiple times but I am fairly certain it is called only once

Comment: I'm guessing prior to this you are setting `var view = tableView.tableHeaderView` ? What do you see if you put a Breakpoint there? `height` gets set to 10000? What are the initial values of `view.Frame` ?